# How can I improve this SQL query？

Tags: sql

I'm a newbie here and I have a table to store some test results.

The columns can be simplified to 2 columns:

```
EXECUTION_ID int(6) CASE_ID int(11)
RESULT varchar(10).
```

And the column "RESULT" is actually a enumeration, save the value in **'PASS'**,**'FAIL'**,**'NORESULT'**.

Now I want to use one sql query to get statistics of all the executions.

The result set format like:

```
EXECUTION_ID | PASS_CNT FAIL_CNT  |  NORESULT_CNT
```

I can only find one way to implement it like this:

```
select A.execId,A.a,B.a,C.a from
    (select execId,result,count(result) a from STAT_RESULTS group by execId,result having result='PASS') A left join
    (select execId,result,count(result) a from STAT_RESULTS group by execId,result having result='FAIL') B on A.execId=B.execId left join
    (select execId,result,count(result) a from STAT_RESULTS group by execId,result having result='NORESULT') C on A.execId=C.execId;
```

The result lists like this:

```
execId  pass    fail    noresult
55      169     77      null
56      46      9       1
57      120     13      3
58      91      45      null
59      95      44      null
60      179     9       5
```

Is there any better way to do the same thing?

Thank you!

Comment: What database engine should this be for? MySQL, Oracle, ...? Check out this article http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78

Comment: @s.bandara: As there are enum types involved, it can almost only be MySQL

Comment: Great, then that tutorial is just the right thing for him.

Comment: @s.bandara Thanks a lot! That's what I need! I'm just using mysql, but I still want to know if there exists a common solution for all the databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about it?

```
select 
s.execid EXECUTION_ID
,sum(case when s.result='PASS' then 1 else 0 end) PASS_CNT 
,sum(case when s.result='FAIL' then 1 else 0 end) FAIL_CNT
,sum(case when s.result='NORESULT' then 1 else 0 end) NORESULT_CNT
from STAT_RESULTS s
group by s.execid
```